# ReactJS set state of another class through props callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to make fullcalendar play nice with ReactJS and Bootstrap modal.
What I want is whenever user choose a date, a bootstrap modal will appear with selected date.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/16j1se1q/1/
```

This is my code

```
class Application extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <FullCalendar />
        );
    }
}

class FullCalendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {view: {showModal: false}};
    }

    handleHideModal(){
        this.setState({view: {showModal: false}})
    }

    handleShowModal(){
        this.setState({view: {showModal: true}})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div is id="calendar" class="bootswatch-flatly"></div>
                {this.state.view.showModal ? <AppointmentPopup handleHideModal={this.handleHideModal}/> : null}
            </div>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var _that = this;
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            /* ... */
            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                /* ... */
                _that.handleShowModal();
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
    }
}

class AppointmentPopup extends React.Component {
    htmlTemplate() {
        return (
            /* ... */
        )
    }

    render() {
        return this.htmlTemplate();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var _that = this;
        $('.appointment-modal').modal({
            show: true,
            keyboard: false,
            backdrop: 'static'
        }).on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
            /* ... */
        });
        $('.appointment-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', this.props.handleHideModal);
    }
    propTypes:{
        handleHideModal: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

My full source code is at: `http://pastebin.com/MZbVqYFZ`

It works fine until I click on a date then close modal.
The problem was caused because that state view.showModal didn't change.
I got the error:
`this.setState is not a function`
It seems that `this.props.handleHideModal` was called successfully but somehow `this` is not ReactJS object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReactJS used to automatically `bind` the component to the method for you. But with es6 style components you're expected to do it yourself as in:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div is id="calendar" class="bootswatch-flatly"></div>
            {this.state.view.showModal ? <AppointmentPopup handleHideModal={this.handleHideModal.bind(this)}/> : null}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @konoufo's suggestion: you need to bind your callback function with your instance scope. Some people prefer doing it this way:

```
class FullCalendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {view: {showModal: false}};

        // add this line to your constructor
        this.handleHideModal = this.handleHideModal.bind(this);
    }

    // ... rest of your code
}
```